# How to hide a text with media queries when user agent stylesheets and display flex overwrite my media query?

Tags: html, css, sass

Well, I am working on a web just to practice HTML, CSS and SASS and it looks like that:

[image]

It is like Netflix, ¿right? Ok, so when the screen size is more little than 1280px, I want the text Warner Live, in the header, to disappear. It would be `display:none`, something easy, right? Well, let's go to the code:

```
.platform-title {
            display: flex;
            flex-flow: row wrap;
            align-content: center;
            margin-left: 5px;
            width: 7vw;

            @media screen and (min-width: 1280px) {
                display: hidden !important;
            }
        }
```

This is the code of that piece of text that says "Warner Live". And let's check Chrome Dev Tools:

[image]
[image]

I dont find a way to hide that text when the screen size is more little. The `display:flex` overwrite the `display:none` and even if I delete the `display:flex`, the `display:block` of the user agent overwrites my `display:none`. Any idea to get the desired result for that text when the size of the screen is under 1280px? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use **display: none** not hidden. This property does not have a hidden value.